# .htaccess redirect for images from old folder to new dynamically created folder structure

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I saw the following answer on a similar question:

```
//301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 /blog/wp-content/uploads/(.*) /wp-content/uploads/$1
```

Which is great, but I have an additional question on this:
Say I have the following structure:

examples:

```
/blog/photos/default/1234/.photos/filename.jpg
/blog/photos/default/12/.photos/filename2.jpg
/blog/photos/default/123456/.photos/filename3.jpg
```

and they now need to be redirect to:

```
/blog/photos/default/id/3/4/1234/.photos/filename.jpg
/blog/photos/default/id/1/2/12/.photos/filename2.jpg
/blog/photos/default/id/5/6/123456/.photos/filename3.jpg
```

As you can see, ther is now an additional structure there: /id/x/y where x is the 2nd to last digit of the original id and y is the last digit.

How can this be done?
(there will not be a case where there is less than 2 digits, but the old id can be like 25 digits long..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule for that:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^(/blog/photos/default)/(\d*(\d)(\d)/.+)$ $1/id/$3/$4/$2
```